# Max/Min value(without field name) in mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb, max, min

I am using the below mentioned MongoDB query in Java to find the maximun value of field `price`:

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,fields).sort(new BasicDBObject("price",1)).limit(1);
```

`fields` argument passing to `coll.find` function here is having the `price` field only.

So I am getting the output in the form:

```
{"price" : value}
```

Is there any way to get value only in the output without the field name and braces etc, so that it can be assigned to a variable or returned to the calling function etc.

Or if there is any other query or mechanism available that I can use for the same purpose.

Pls suggest..

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of price from the DBCursor object as follows.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Double price = (Double) cursor.next().get("price");
}
```

On the mongo shell you can do it as follows :

```
db.priceObj.find({},{_id:0, price:1}).sort({price:-1}).limit(1)[0].price
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this due to the fact that MongoDB communicates using BSON.

A single value like you want would be invalid BSON. It is easy enough to filter it out your side.